# Initialize rospy in rqt_plugin

Tags: rospy, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to write a simple rqt_plugin for ROS Groovy in Python. The plugin is located in a rosbuild package.
My plugin is supposed to publish to a topic using data entered in the UI created with qt-designer.
I already can start the UI to fill a visualization_msgs::Marker message with the according current data.
I can also use my plugin both standalone (rosrun my_pkg my_plugin) as well as with rqt.

However, after starting the pulugin, there is no ROS node initialized for it. Thus, also the topic is not advertised and I get an error when calling the publish() function of the Publisher I created in the plugin
Error Message: `rospy.exceptions.ROSException: ROS node has not been initialized yet. Please call init_node() first`

As I read in the tutorial, the plugin itself should not call init_node() as rqt is doing this.
So where does this initialization happen? Do I need to overload a certain function?
My plugin is derived from rqt_gui_py.plugin.Plugin.
I use a separate my_plugin_widget class similar to the existing rqt_plugins (e.g. rqt_publisher).

One thing, I found is that I need to set qt_gui_py::Plugin as the base_class_type within the plugin.xml

```
<class name="MirorRGB" type="miror_rqt_gui.miror_rgb.MirorRGB" base_class_type="qt_gui_py::Plugin">
...
</class>
```

Also, I need to have

```
  <export>
     <qt_gui plugin="${prefix}/plugin.xml"/>
  </export>
```

in my manifest.xml in order to be able to find my plugin with rqt --list-plugins and to be able to start it.

This is different from what the tutorials on the ROS wiki states where rqt_gu_py::Plugin is used in the plugin.xml and rqt_gui in the manifest.xml.

I hope someone is able to help.
If more information on my setup is needed, feel free to ask.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125871/initialize-rospy-in-rqt_plugin/) by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo in both *plugin.xml* and *package.xml*. It's **rqt_gui** not qt_gui

Use `rqt_gui_py::Plugin` as the base class in your *plugin.xml* file and use

```
<export>
  <rqt_gui plugin="${prefix}/plugin.xml"/>
</export>
```

in the *manifest.xml*

EDIT: Just realized you use rosbuild. But it's still **rqt_gui**
Have a look at this answer: `answers.ros.org/question/65679/install-rqt-plugin-with-rosbuild/?answer=65698#post-id-65698` and the rqt_console code for fuerte: `github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/tree/fuerte-devel/rqt_console`

(Sorry for the unformatted links - my karma is insufficient...)

---

Originally posted by [PiotrOrzechowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/9741/piotrorzechowski/) with karma: 36 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1